# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'teams.team_b_id' in 'where clause'

Tags: laravel

I have a `competitions` table and it has the following fields.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('competitions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->foreignId('team_a_id')->constrained('teams')->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->foreignId('team_b_id')->constrained('teams')->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->string('date');
        $table->string('time');
        $table->string('league');
        $table->string('end_at');
        $table->string('live')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

And I want to search `team_a_id`  and `team_b_id` in the teams' table.

Competition.php

```
public function team()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Team::class, 'team_a_id', 'team_b_id');
}
```

CompetitionController.php

```
public function index()
{
    $keyword = request('search') ?? null;
    $competitions = Competition::query()
        ->whereHas('team', function ($query) use ($keyword) {
            $query->where('title' , 'LIKE' , "%{$keyword}%");
        })->paginate(25);
    return view('Admin.competitions.index', compact('competitions'));
}
```

error

[image: sql]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third parameter for BelongsTo is the Key in the other table ('id' as default), you can't do what you tried, the simplest solution would be to have 2 relationship, one for each team.

```
    public function teamA()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Team::class, 'team_a_id';
}


    public function teamB()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Team::class, 'team_b_id';
}
```

and do the same logic that you have now, but adding a OrWhereHas

```
$competitions = Competition::query()
->whereHas('teamA', function ($query) use ($keyword) {
            $query->where('title' , 'LIKE' , "%{$keyword}%");
        })
->orWhereHas('teamB', function ($query) use ($keyword) {
            $query->where('title' , 'LIKE' , "%{$keyword}%");
        })->paginate(25);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must pass the primary key of the table **teams** here on the parameter 3:

```
public function team()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Team::class, 'team_a_id', '**ID_TEAM**');
}
```

Comment: And of course you have to create 2 relations, one for teamA() and another to TeamB()